# A semicolon to suppress output does not work in IPython

Tags: ipython, suppression

In the documentation at *[IPython Tips & Tricks](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/tips.html)*, it says to put a semicolon (;) at the end of a command to suppress its output. This does not seem to work in my case as even a

```python
print('Hello');
```

outputs

```
Hello
```

Do I have the wrong idea of output suppression or is this a bug? This is especially annoying when working in [PuDB](https://pypi.org/project/pudb/), as it flashes horribly in my case as I press 'next' or 'step into'.

P.S.: The output is neither on my [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) IPython 0.10 nor [OS X v10.7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Lion) (Lion) IPython 0.11 suppressed. Although the flashing issue is worse in OS X, probably because of item2.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try something like `1 + 1;`. Without the semicolon, it should give you feedback about the result by printing it (formatted by `repr`, though it doesn't matter in the case of integers) - I assume that it's this output that's supposed to be suppressed.

The shell doesn't (and shouldn't) suppress writing to the file that happens to be referenced by `sys.stdout` (which is essentially what `print` does). This is an entirely different matter, and not the job of the shell.

Comment: Just to confirm, delnan is quite right about this - it's the result of an expression that you can suppress, not printing things.

Comment: Thank you for your fast and concise answer, though I am disappointed that it does not do what I hoped for I am thankful for clearing that up.

Answer (score 6):

Add `%%capture` as the first line of the cell. For example,

```
%%capture
print('Hello')
```

This simply discards the output, but the `%%capture` magic can be used to save the output to a variable—[consult the documentation](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Cell%20Magics.ipynb).

Answer (score 1):

Here's another example from the [Dataquest — 28 Jupyter Notebook tips, tricks, and shortcuts](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/jupyter-notebook-tips-tricks-shortcuts/) post:

```
  # Use a semicolon to suppress the output of a final function.
  %matplotlib inline
  from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
  import numpy
  x = numpy.linspace(0, 1, 1000)**1.5
  plt.hist(x); # Output not suppressed w/ semicolon?
```

And an example of a "working" semicolon suppression:

```
x = 1 + 1
x; # Output suppressed with semicolon!
```

So it appears to suppress *for* statements that would normally show up in the terminal, but not "inline" types, like plots.