How to disable semicolon autoformatting in IPython?
In IPython, if I type
In [1]: x = 1; y = 2; print(x + y)

Then when I press the up arrow, I get
In [2]: x = 2
   ...: y = 3
   ...: print(x + y)

so IPython is changing my one-liner to a three-liner.
Is it possible to disable this behavior?

Which IPython version do you use? I cannot reproduce this in IPython 8.5.0.

Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500754/a-semicolon-to-suppress-output-does-not-work-in-ipython

@mkrieger1 I was on 8.0. When I upgraded to 8.26.0, the behavior disappeared. If you want to make that an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks.
